# PHP: How to Populate HTML Elements Based on Parent Class Attribute

Tags: php, html, xml, seo, facebook-opengraph

I have a custom TV schedule that I manually update using a static `<table>`. Each `<tr>` has 5 `<td>` children of which each contain one of the following in this order: date, time, competition, match, and TV channel.

```
<table>
  <tr><th>DATE</th><th>TIME</th><th>COMPETITION</th><th>MATCH</th><th>CHANNEL</th></tr>
  <tr class="comp-1 ch-1">
    <td>October 17</td>
    <td>5 PM</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Team Alpha v Team Bravo</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have the following `PHP Array`:

```
<?php
  $comps = [
    'comp-1' => 'Tug-of-War',
    'comp-2' => 'Tag Rugby',
    'comp-3' => 'Handball',
    'comp-4' => 'The Gauntlet',
  ];

  $channels = [
    'ch-1' => 'Channel 1',
    'ch-2' => 'Channel 2',
    'ch-3' => 'Channel 3',
    'ch-4' => 'Channel 4',
  ];
?>
```

What I want to do is have the empty `<td>` cells automatically populate based on their `<tr>` parent's `class` attribute values. I need to do this in PHP for XML, SEO and OGP purposes. Previously, it was done using jQuery but a test using [Google's Rich Snippets Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets) shows that the empty `<td>` cells are being read as empty when the page loads.

If anyone can help me with any ideas on how to acheive this I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Assign a variable in each row (hopefully in the `foreach` statement you're using...) to correspond to the number in each array, then increment them at the end of each loop.

```
$comp_row_id = 1;
$ch_row_id = 1;

$competition = $comps['comp-' . $comp_row_id]; // Tug-of-War
$channel = $comps['ch-' . $ch_row_id]; // Channel 1

$comp_row_id++;
$ch_row_id++;
```

If `$comp_row_id` and `$ch_row_id` are always going to be the same, just combine those variables into one called `$i` or similar for consistency.